# request_head with basic_auth

Tags: ruby, http-headers

I want to know the response code without getting the whole page content, so I use `#request_head`. But I get "401", so I need to pass login/password:

```
require "net/http"

uri = URI.parse "http://example.com/some_path"

connection = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 80)

connection.basic_auth "qwe", "rty"

p connection.request_head uri.path
```

but I get

> temp.rb:9:in `<main>': undefined method`basic_auth' for #<Net::HTTP staging.new.inmyroom.ru:80

since `#basic_auth` belongs to another class:

```
connection = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.host
```

that doesn't have `#request_head`:

> temp.rb:10:in `<main>': undefined method`request_head' for #<Net::HTTP::Get GET> (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HEAD` HTTP verb.

From RFC2616:

> This method (HEAD) can be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the request >  without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification.

Something like that:

```
require "net/http"

uri = URI('YOUR_URL')

req = Net::HTTP::Head.new(uri)
req.basic_auth('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(req)
end
```

`res` contains a `#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK  readbody=true>` object.

Comment: Note, if you getting 
Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer
Just add use_ssl option to HTTP.start call
Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, use_ssl: uri.scheme == 'https')

Answer (score 0):

I managed to pass `Get`'s header to `#request_head` but its header hash values should be flattened:

```
get = Net::HTTP::Get.new url

get.basic_auth "qwe", "rty"

fixed_header = Hash[ get.to_hash.map{ |k,v| [k,v[0]] } ]

Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
  p http.request_head(uri.path, fixed_header)
end
```